# Check username or phone already exist (front)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, sequelize.js

I would like to know if an user or a phone exists on my front form,

I do not wait for the answer but something to tell me to do it.

I use Yup + Formik for my all requires.

On my backend with Sequelize I managed to display if a username or phone existed :

```
passport.use(
    'register',
    new LocalStrategy(
        {
            usernameField: 'username',
            passwordField: 'password',
            passReqToCallback: true,
            session: false,
        },
        (req, username, password, done) => {
            console.log(username);
            console.log(req.body.phone)
            try {
                User.findOne({
                    where: {
                        [Op.or]: [
                            {
                                username,
                            },
                            { phone: req.body.phone },
                        ],
                    },
                }).then(user => {
                    if (user != null) {
                        console.log('username or phone already taken');
                        return done(null, false, {
                            message: 'username or phone already taken',
                        });
                    }
                    bcrypt.hash(password, BCRYPT_SALT_ROUNDS).then(hashedPassword => {
                        User.create({
                            username,
                            password: hashedPassword,
                            phone: req.body.phone,
                        }).then(user => {
                            console.log('user created');
                            return done(null, user);
                        });
                    });
                });
            } catch (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
        },
    ),
);
```

But I have a hard time understanding this on my front, I think I can get this information in my axios .catch ? :

```
const onSubmit = async function onSubmit(values) {
        axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:4242/registerUser',
            data: values,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        })
            .then(() => {
                setModalOpen(true);
                setUsername(nameRef.current.value);
                setRedirect(true);
                setCount(4);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
            });
    };

return (
        <div className="container-all-form">
            <Formik
                initialValues={initialValues}
                validate={validate(getValidationSchema)}
                onSubmit={onSubmit}
            >
// my form
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your catch block in your onSubmit function, you should be able to access the message produced by the backend if you do:

`console.log(error.response.message)`

Then you can set some value in state to conditionally display an error message to the user that the username/phone exists in your backend. When submitting the form again, you can clear this state to remove the error message while the api call executes.

Comment: for the moment i use that `catch((error) => {
    if (error.response.status === 403) {
     alert('Pseudo or phone alreay exist !');
   };`
Thx !

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in 2 ways. One is you can use error.response.message in your catch block.

Other way is you can use statuses and log error in your then function like :

```
.then(res => res.json())
    .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200 || response.status === 201) {

            setModalOpen(true);
            setUsername(nameRef.current.value);
            setRedirect(true);
            setCount(4);
        }
        else {
            console.log(response.message)
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err.response.message)
    })
```

Comment: Sorry I am just new to stack overflow. I would need suggestions on what formatting is required

Comment: I have done it for you, you need to put your pasted code in (``) backticks

Comment: Taking advantage of await/async feature in ES6 will make the world much better...  use it in IIFE pattern can help to integrate it into the legacy code.

Comment: for the moment i use that `catch((error) => {
    if (error.response.status === 403) {
     alert('Pseudo or phone alreay exist !');
   };`
Thx !